# Perform a logical test over a group_by() of rows, but mutate the rows individually?

Tags: r, dplyr

## Question:

How do I perform a logical test over a group of rows, but have the output performed on individual rows in R?

### Setup:

I have two items, each broken into 4 quarters of a year.  If I shipped just 1 time during the year, I need to do follow-on calculations on that quarter, but if I have no shipments during the year, I need show `NA` so that I can exclude it from those calculations.

```r
df <- data.frame(item = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)),
                 value = c(0, NA, 5, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA))

> df
  item value
1    A     0
2    A    NA
3    A     5
4    A     1
5    B     0
6    B    NA
7    B    NA
8    B    NA
```

### Desired Output

The end result should be this:

```r
  item  value new_value
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A         0         0
2 A        NA         0
3 A         5         5
4 A         1         1
5 B         0        NA
6 B        NA        NA
7 B        NA        NA
8 B        NA        NA
```

### What I Have Tried:

I'm generally using the `library(tidyverse)`, but I'm not absolutely wedded to it if there's a base solution.  My first thought, however, throws an error:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  mutate(new_value = if_else(sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)>0, coalesce(value, 0), NA_real_))

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `new_value = if_else(sum(value, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, coalesce(value, 0), NA_real_)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: item = "A".
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 4.
```

I'm only using the `group_by()` in order to have the `sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` act over the group, but then I want the `coalesce()` to act on each individual row.  I also know that `dplyr`'s `if_else()` operates differently than the base `ifelse()`, so I tried that:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  mutate(new_value = ifelse(sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)>0, coalesce(value, 0), NA_real_))

# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   item [2]
  item  value new_value
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A         0         0
2 A        NA         0
3 A         5         0   # should be '5'
4 A         1         0   # should be '1'
5 B         0        NA
6 B        NA        NA
7 B        NA        NA
8 B        NA        NA
```

...which is closer to the desired output, but it appears to only use the first row in the group, and I want the action to be on each individual row, as you see in the Desired Output above.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `if`/`else` instead of `ifelse` because there is a single condition per group to check rather than a condition per row.

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(value = if (any(value > 0, na.rm = TRUE)) pmax(value, 0, na.rm = TRUE) else NA, .by = item)

  item value
1    A     0
2    A     0
3    A     5
4    A     1
5    B    NA
6    B    NA
7    B    NA
8    B    NA
```

Comment: Thank you.  This answer I think generalizes the type of problem I'm trying to solve the best.  I actually didn't know that I had a third option for `if else` constructions inside mutate: `if_else()`; `ifelse()`; and `if (condition) TRUE else FALSE`, so that is enlightening (I thought it could only be used in main part of script for flow control).  I'm still using `dplyr 1.0.10` so a call out for the person to pass by is that your use of `.by = item` is the experimental feature added in `dplyr 1.1.0`.  Outcome is the same, but Q: Why did you choose `pmax()` instead of `coalesce()`? Thanks!

Comment: You could likely use either - I used `pmax()` because from the description of your problem you presumably aren't dealing with negative values and it is likely to be faster than `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use:

```
df %>%
   group_by(item) %>%
   mutate(new_val = coalesce(value,0) * any(value>0))

# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   item [2]
  item  value new_val
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         0       0
2 A        NA       0
3 A         5       5
4 A         1       1
5 B         0      NA
6 B        NA      NA
7 B        NA      NA
8 B        NA      NA
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and probably the best answer for this specific problem I presented as an example.  It gets away from the `if-else` paradigm and I would guess achieves the result most efficiently both from length of code and probably performance (?).  I would like to think like this more often.  My only hesitancy for not accepting this as the answer is that I'm not sure it would work for all variants of this type of problem (one that doesn't use `NA` or something else like that where the `if-else` construction would be necessary and generalizes better.  Thank you.

Comment: @wackojacko1997 the only time this will not work is if value was a character. But thai is not true in your case

Answer (score 1):

## Possible Answer

As I got ready to post the question, one of the suggestions from SO pointed me to this similar  [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110978/group-by-and-pmap-a-piecewise-operation-on-each-row-per-group-ifelse-vs-case-wh)

Reading @akrun's answer, I tried adding the repetition function to the logical test, and got the result I want:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  mutate(new_value = ifelse(rep(sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)>0,n()), coalesce(value, 0), NA_real_))
```

[image: Working solution]

I'm really curious if there are other solutions out there that might be better or just good to know as alternatives, so I'm not going to accept this answer until I've given this some time to marinade.